# VM characteristics in Azure-PaaS?

Tags: windows, azure, virtual-machines

I have a technical query on Azure PaaS service features. This is related to my ongoing research at the University of Liverpool,UK as part of my Post Graduation in MS Big Data Analytics. Please forward the below query to your Azure technical consultants.

I have a query on Azure PaaS cloud computing.  I'm aware that we can create VMs on IaaS. Can we create VMs on PaaS? Like in Azure PaaS?.  I want to run my custom software on Intel CPU only and test. I know in IaaS I can create VM image of specific OS say Windows x64 and specific CPU say Intel. For PaaS, can I create VM with Intel x86 based Windows 7 OS?. Can Azure allow me to request specific underlying VM characteristics in Azure-PaaS please?.

regards
sachindeo

Comment: ServerFault != Microsoft

Answer (score 1):

on Azure like most PAAS Services Platforms you cannot specify the underlying hardware platform, and also the whole point of PAAS is to abstract the underlying infrastructure. I understand that you might need a specific feature set in a processor and for that you need to use VMs.

In PAAS service (in Azure: App Service, Functions) you can specify things like Linux or Windows but that's pretty much all.
Hope this helps.